# How to show mandatory name fields in Propertygrid(Exntended wpf toolkit version 3.4.0 )

Tags: wpf, propertygrid

I am using **Propertygrid from Extended WPF toolkit version 3.4.0** in my **WPF** Appliacation.
I am using **SelectedObject** of PropertyGrid. Everything works fine

But how can i indicate user that few fields in **SelectedObject** a**re mandatory to fill by user in PropertyGrid?**
Currently i am using **DisplayName** attribute in model object as follows . But its not  that catchy for user. **Is it possible to show * in DisplayName with red color in name fields or show complete name field of mandatory fields in bold in PropertyGrid?**  . I am attaching images to show how i actually wants in PropertyGrid. Can anybody suggest how to do it?
Thanks in advance.
[image: I want that * at end of mandatory name fields in red color] or the complete name field in Bold [1]]

```
 [CategoryAttribute("Category Name"),DisplayName("PropertyDisplayName *"), DescriptionAttribute("Property Description")]
    public string PropertyName 
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyName ;
        }
        set
        {
            _propertyName = Value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: From what you're asking it sounds like you need to be creating custom styles for the controls in the `PropertyGrid`, check out this link for styling an existing control [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/customizing-the-appearance-of-an-existing-control)

Comment: Thanks Coops for comment.Anyway I solved the issue by EditingTemplate of PropertyGrid

Comment: No worries dude, glad to be of help 

Answer (score 0):

Edit Template of PropertyGrid. You will find **TrimmedTextBlock** named "**_text**" under **PART_Name**. Bind Foreground property as follows with a Converter based on our requirement.

```
Foreground="{Binding DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource mandatoryFieldColorConverter} }"
```